# Remove Sunday in .toLocaleDateString() javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a javascript function that will add 18 months to a date

```
function plus18months(d) {
    var d2 = new Date(d);
    d2.setMonth(d2.getMonth() + 18);
    return d2;
}

var d = new Date(2000, 0, 1);

alert(plus18months(d).toLocaleDateString());
```

it will output `Sunday, July 01, 2001`

How do I remove the `Sunday` in the output and return a date having a format of `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Hmm,`.toLocaleDateString()` outputs `"14-1-2014"` here... weird.

Comment: And `13/01/2014` here. It's a **locale** date string, which changes depending on your regional settings.

Comment: When pasting your code in console, I get `1-7-2001`. What browser are you using? This is tested in Chrome.

Comment: `substring` is what you want

Comment: @Vache I don't know why different locale settings would also make a difference in number or written out...

Comment: @MarijnS95 What? You get July 1st 2001 and so does he...

Comment: @Vache I am getting the numbers: `1-7-2001`, not `July 01, 2001`

Comment: @MarijnS95 im using firefox

Comment: @Bongsky this is weird. You might look into substring, but not every day has the same lengh(monday has 6, wednesday 9 etc). Try the different to... in your console and find wich one works, else you want to do `date.getDay() + '-'+date.getMonth()` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is great, but to keep your `yyyy-mm-dd` formatting, use this:

```
x = new Date;
x.getFullYear()+'-'+x.getMonth()+1+'-'+x.getDate();
```

Output: `"2014-01-14"`

Comment: I missed the last part in the question that mentioned having a `yyyy-mm-dd` final format. I deleted my answer this is the way to go (though calling a constructor without the parentheses might be frown upon depending on which side of the JSLint fence you stand ;) ).